# Missing port option in arduino ide

Tags: c++

The port option in Arduino Uno IDE is not accessible.

I have win7 32bit, I have tried the installation of driver file arduino.inf, but still it is not working

Comment: Could you please provide more detail by specifying exactly what you are doing and what the problem is? I encourage you to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for guidance on asking [good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on this site.

Comment: the arduino and arduono-ide tags will likely be far more useful in attracting the audience you want than the C++ tag.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because windows did not recognize any com ports. Go to device manager and look for COM ports. Check if it shows up there or not.

If not, then that means windows did not recognize it and there is a connection problem